# Best Python module for Berkeley DB?

Tags: python, berkeley-db

According to the Python 2.6.5 docs [1], the bsddb module has been deprecated for removal in Python 3.0.

What module/wrapper should I be using instead?

[1] http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html

Comment: Those looking for equivalent functionality may be interested to know that the [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module uses [anydbm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html) underneath by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend [pyBSDdb](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm) (from which the version currently in Python standard's library was taken -- but the stand-alone project is more actively maintained and far from deprecated;-).